# Checking if an array has been assigned a size yet

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any way to check if an array has already been set to a length in Java?

In my case, I have a recursive method, and in the first iteration of the method, I want the array to have the length of a variable n. However, after the first recursion of the method, I don't want the array to be reassigned a new size.

Additionally, I don't know what the size should be until the first iteration of the method.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste that piece or part of that code which can give a better understanding.

Comment: Why do you need array, ArrayList can be a better option

Comment: Can you put the first "iteration" outside the loop?

Answer (score 4):

The array variable would be null until you assign an instance to it. Once an instance is assigned, it will have a fixed length. Therefore, a simple null check would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The Array Reference Variable Would be NULL until you assign to it.

You cannot create an Array Object without a lenght; if you want that, maybe you should create a ArrayList, and you can add objects to it without care about the size.

If you just want to see the lenght of your Array; after CREATE, do this:

```
public static void main (String[] args){


        String[] x = new String[2]; // you cannot create here without a lenght, you MUST set 
        System.out.println(x.length);


}
```

OUTPUT: 2